# java azure web app No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

Tags: java, sql, azure

I have a java app that accesses sql server DB on Azure, when I run the app locally I have no issues connecting to the DB, however once I deploy the app(.war) to Azure app service instance I then get 'No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver'. My pom.xml file has

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.jre10</version>
</dependency>
```

And I can see in the the jar file in the web-INF/lib folder so I am not sure what could be missing, any help would be great.

Comment: What is your connection string look like?

Answer (score 0):

@user1953901 - Please share the maven command you used to run the sample.
This message would indicate that the classpath is not setup properly.